# Source for the four questions you're asked at the gates

Tags: sources-mekorot, death

I've seen references to the "four questions you're asked at the gates (after death)" --

1. Were you honest in your business dealings?
2. Did you set aside regular time for Torah study?
3. Did you have / attempt to have a family?
4. Did you look forward to the future time of the mashiach?

**Q What is the source for this list?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Shabbat 31a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.31a.11?lang=bi):

> אָמַר רָבָא: בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁמַּכְנִיסִין אָדָם לְדִין, אוֹמְרִים לוֹ: נָשָׂאתָ וְנָתַתָּ בָּאֱמוּנָה? קָבַעְתָּ עִתִּים לַתּוֹרָה? עָסַקְתָּ בִּפְרִיָּה וּרְבִיָּה? צָפִיתָ לִישׁוּעָה? פִּלְפַּלְתָּ בְּחׇכְמָה? הֵבַנְתָּ דָּבָר מִתּוֹךְ דָּבָר?‏
>
> Rava said: After departing from this world, when a person is brought to judgment for the life he lived in this world, they say to him in the order of that verse: Did you conduct business faithfully? Did you designate times for Torah study? Did you engage in procreation? Did you await salvation? Did you engage in the dialectics of wisdom or understand one matter from another?

(And note that it's really six questions, derived exegetically from [Isaiah 33:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.33.6?lang=bi).)